# What are some ways I can secure my piano stand so it isn't moving as much?

Tags: piano, digital-piano, equipment

I just got the L85 stand for Yamaha P95 (with 3-pedal LP5), assembled the whole thing, and when I started playing, I noticed that it is moving quite a bit when I play something faster, or just hit the keys harder.

From looking at youtube videos, it seems that it is quite normal for the piano to move around a bit (around 1-2cm backward/forward).

**Is this a result of a bad technique, or is it just how low-end stands are built?** Are there some ways that I can secure my stand so that isn't moving as much?

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is due to low quality stands and often the weight of the keyboard but also the resonance effect. When you hit the keys at the left or right end in a certain rhythm you increase the wobbling.

What you can do is attach the mount to a wall with some cheap brackets or just build your own frame from wood which is based on triangles. You won't have any wobbling then but here your frame has to weight enough to have enough mass or the whole construction will still wobble due to your keyboard being heavier. Even nicer is to mount the frame to a wall and it will be rock solid.

Answer (score 3):

Your stand is probably of lower quality. Vibration caused by lower notes and forceful playing contribute to moving the stand, and it also gets worse with time by loosening the joints, screws and bolts (natural effect).

Another thing that can contribute to such problem is the levelling of the floor over which your stand lies. Joints between tiles, poorly settled wood floors or subtle inclination can lead to unpleasant unstability of the stand.

One possible solution is to put some form of wedge beneath one or two of the corners of the stand. Press down either side of the stand and check if the corners move up, leaving a gap to the floor. Put the wedge there, adjusting its thickness until the stand settles firmly.

Another good measure is to periodically re-screw every joint and connection of your base, checking for unreversible damage to the screw holes. In such cases, you can exchange current screws for longer or thicker ones, always taking care to avoid cracking/breaking the stand material due to overpressure.

Answer (score 2):

From looking into the L85 stand image on the web (two parallel vertical boards), the most probable reason is that your floor may not be perfectly flat. Check if one of the corners of the stand is not hanging in the air rather than standing on the floor. If you observe a gap there, put something under that corner to close it.

Answer (score -1):

We want our keyboards and stands to be lightweight enough to be portable, but heavy enough to stand firm. Not always a possible combination.   You could consider using a stand-alone music stand - something more substantial than the flimsy metal fold-up type - behind the keyboard.   On gigs I often have to use my knee to steady a bouncing keyboard!

Answer (score -2):

I made my own stand! £20 for an 8x4 18mm mdf sheet and some paint[image]

Comment: I don't immediately see how this answers the question.

Comment: Hi Dekkadeci, yes your right! To be more specific when I made my own stand, I added two brackets on the side legs of the stand that screw into the keyboard base (M5x20 for Yamaha P45 and P115) and what stopped the whole stand moving was adding the two ski type support rails on the base of each side panel. I then purchased some non slip rubber flat feet which I glued to the bottom of the ski’s.